# how to specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for multiple domains?

Tags: http-headers

I"m thinking of using my NextJS API endpoints for my React app and wanted to see if the following is possible, before I create a separate app to test for this.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo1.example, https://foo2.example, https://foo3.example
```